# Using stored procedure to retrieve data from database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm using a stored procedure to pull a list of items from a database however I keep getting this error:

> Procedure or function 'requisition_sp_getItemNum' expects parameter '@reqNumber', which was not supplied.

I have use the hiddenfor in order to supply the reqNumber but that throws the same error message

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[requisition_sp_getItemNum]
    @reqNumber VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        a.ITEMNMBR, a.ITEMDESC, ab.employee_id, 
        ab.department, ab.employee_name, quantity_requested,
        b.expense_acc, c.ACTDESCR + '/' + c.ACTNUMBR_1 + '-' + c.ACTNUMBR_2 [Expense_Acc],
        b.unit_of_measure
    FROM
        [TWCL].[dbo].IV00101 a 
    INNER JOIN
        RequisitionItem b ON a.ITEMNMBR = b.item_no
    INNER JOIN
        Requisition ab ON ab.Req_No = b.Req_No
    INNER JOIN
        [TWCL].dbo.GL00100 c ON b.expense_acc = c.ACTINDX 
    WHERE
        b.Req_No = @reqNumber AND ab.status = -1
END
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <hr/>


          <table id="data">

            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th >@Html.CheckBox("TheOneCheckBoxToRuleThemAll")Select All</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Date</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Requisition Number</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Expense Account</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">Requestor</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">Department</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">LoggedinAs</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Item Number</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Description</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1">Quantity</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1 ">UOM</th>

                    </tr>

            <tbody>





               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {


                   foreach (var item in Model[i].items)
                   {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].reqNumber)
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].reqNumber)</td>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].postTrnx, new { @class = "checkGroup1" })</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata" >@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].reqDate)</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata" >@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].reqNumber)</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.expense_account.account_desc</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.employeeDetails.employeeNum</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.employeeDetails.department</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.employeeDetails.LoggedInUserName</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.itemNumber</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.description</td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.quantity</td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.selecteduomtext </td>

                            @*<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @item.lineNum, name = Model[i].reqNumber })</td>*@
                        </tr>

                    }

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Model

```
 public List<Item> getRequestItemByRquisition(string reqNumber)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        SqlConnection TWCLOPConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
        SqlCommand itemscommand = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader itemRdr;
        itemscommand.CommandText = "requisition_sp_getItemNum ";
        itemscommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        itemscommand.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
        itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqNumber;

        try
        {
            TWCLOPConnect.Open();
            itemRdr = itemscommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (itemRdr.Read())
            {


                Item item = new Item();

                item.itemNumber = itemRdr.GetString(0);
                item.description = itemRdr.GetString(1);

                item.employeeDetails.employeeNum = Convert.ToInt32(itemRdr.GetString(2));
                item.employeeDetails.department = itemRdr.GetString(3);
                item.employeeDetails.LoggedInUserName = itemRdr.GetString(4);
                item.quantity = Convert.ToDouble(itemRdr[5]);
                item.expense_account.index = itemRdr.GetInt32(6);
                item.expense_account.account_desc = itemRdr.GetString(7);

               item.selecteduomtext = itemRdr.GetString(8);

                items.Add(item);
            }
            itemRdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            TWCLOPConnect.Close();
        }

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Look at the name of your parameter in the procedure (reqNumber) and the name in your code (Req_No). They are not the same.

Comment: @SeanLange; besides the mismatch what else would cause this error. How to supply data to reqNumber

Comment: Values for parameters are accessed through the Value property which seem to have in your code.

Comment: But I'm still getting the error so I dont understand

Comment: The value has nothing to do with this error. It is about if you provided the parameter. It is hard to say now because your code has changed in your question. Did you recompile, if you are running this from a server did you post the new bits to the server? Have you tried running sql profiler so you can see the commands being executed?

Comment: Only thing I changed was the name.

Comment: Did you recompile? If you are running this from a server did you post the new bits to the server? Have you tried running sql profiler so you can see the commands being executed?

Comment: Yes and reqNumber does not have a value

Comment: reqNumber the string in dotnet? Are you saying that is an empty string? Because that wouldn't cause the error you are getting.

Comment: I'm saying that it is null; indicating no value is being supplied for reqNumber

Comment: On which side? dotnet or sql server? A NULL value will NOT generate that error message. Your message is stating the parameter is not provided, not that the value is NULL.

Comment: It is going to return a null value because there is parameter set for it

Comment: Huh? What does that mean? The procedure would not return a NULL, it would return an empty resultset. But in your question you stated that you are getting an error message. Are you getting an error message still? Remember that we can't see your screen. All we have to work with is what you post.

Comment: I'm not understanding then because in debugging it says null then when it reaches here itemRdr = itemscommand.ExecuteReader(); throws the error message

Comment: What is null? Your string in dotnet or the variable? I feel like I keep asking you the same thing. Or are you talking about the return from your procedure. Step through your code. Make sure you have a value in your parameter, run the code yourself in SSMS and see what you get. It is nearly impossible for me to debug this for you.

Comment: The variable reqNumber is null, i have executed the stored procedure and it gave the desired results. Because I'm just pulling the data from the database; I'm not supplying the reqNumber with a value; so my question is where do I set the reqNumber

Comment: itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqNumber;

Comment: Notice the Value property? That is where it gets set. do you have value in the string that you are using to set the value? Do you have a value in your parameter after this line?

Comment: no i dont have any vale

Comment: This is like pulling teeth. You have to communicate with information. You don't have any value where??? In the string? In the parameter? In the output?

Comment: Yoh asked if I have any value in the after the line and I'm saying no. There's no value in the string

Comment: Well...the string is being passed into your method from somewhere....perhaps you should look there and see why you are not passing anything in.

Answer (score 0):

You variable from stored procedure `@reqNumber`:

```
@reqNumber varchar (50)
```

and the variable `@Req_No` you added here

```
itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@Req_No", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Req_No;
```

must match.

Change this:

```
itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqNumber;
```

to this:

```
itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", reqNumber);
```

New way: can you change your code to this

```
SqlConnection TWCLOPConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());

SqlCommand itemscommand = new SqlCommand("requisition_sp_getItemNum", TWCLOPConnect);
itemscommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", reqNumber);

SqlDataReader itemRdr;

try
{

}
```

Comment: Can you just run SP by itself  by providing hard coded variable? It must give you the result unless you don't have another problem on it

Comment: yes i can it gave the desired result. but in debugging  itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqNumber; this returns null

Comment: @SujaeBrown This statement ` itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqNumber;` will not return a result; if this returns null `itemscommand.Parameters[0].Value` then `reqNumber` is null...

Comment: How would I supply the value then

Comment: Did you try my updated answer? It is from working example.

Comment: Did you check you passed var? string reqNumber.

Comment: Sorry I did not see it; will try it now

Comment: Did you use this

Comment: Yes i did use this itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", reqNumber); instead of itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqNumber;